# How to do this grid pattern using Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm wondering is this grid a svg? How can i recreate something like this grid using tailwind CSS. I've checked the inspect element can't find any svg. Thanks

[image]

Here is the link
[https://primer.tailwindui.com](https://primer.tailwindui.com/)

I need to do the hover effect when mouse travel. Something like [this](https://xeleron.pages.dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that grid patterns is svg, this is that i see when i try inspect element:

[image: SVG Image]

**CODE:**

```html
  <div class="absolute -bottom-12 -top-20 left-0 right-1/2 z-10 w-screen bg-blue-600 text-white/10 md:bottom-8 lg:-inset-y-32">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="absolute inset-0 h-screen w-screen">
      <defs>
        <pattern id=":S2:" width="128" height="128" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="100%" y="100%" patternTransform="translate(112 64)">
          <path d="M0 128V.5H128" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"></path>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#:S2:)"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

[or copy code from tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XBXxRqi4VR)

Comment: how can i take that svg?

Comment: can you give me the code that you want to put the svg?

Comment: @TharinduJayasanka — You don't "take" it. That would be copyright infringement. You ask the owner for permission.

Comment: @MilanLizriadi just want to add that to the <body><body/>

Comment: @Quentin I just want to recreate something like this thats all.

Comment: try code from my updated answer @TharinduJayasanka

Comment: @MilanLizriadi This is what i want. Thank you :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).